# JavaScript loop ranges and code execution (port scanner)

Tags: javascript, sockets, port

I'm having an issue with calling a function in a loop, with JavaScript.  As I'm new to JavaScript, I thought perhaps my approach must be wrong.  Can someone help me out with the following issue?

Basically, each time I learn a new language, I try and write a port scanner in it.  In Python, I used a for loop to iterate over a range of numbers, passing them in as ports to a host.  It worked fine and I attempted the same approach in JavaScript, with some socket connection code I found online:

```
const net = require('net');

function Scanner(host, port){
    const s = new net.Socket();
    s.setTimeout(2000, function() { s.destroy(); });
    s.connect(port, host, function () {
        console.log('Open: '+ port);
    });
    s.on('data', function(data){
        console.log(port +': ' +data);
        s.destroy();
    });
    s.on('error', function (e) {
        s.destroy();
    })
}

for(let p = 15000; p < 30000; p++){             
    let scan = new Scanner('localhost', p);
}
```

In the above example, I'm iterating over a port range of 15000 to 30000.  It appears to run very fast, giving me two results: port 15292 and 15393 as being open on my test vm.  However, it's not picking up several ports in the 20,000 range, like 27017.

If I narrow the range from 25000 to 30000 it picks those up just fine.  The problem seems to be when I have a larger range, the code isn't discovering anything after a few hits.

In looking at some other JS implementations of port scanners, I noticed the same issue.  It works great when the range is 5,000 ports or so, but scale it up to 20k or 30k ports and it only finds the first few open ones.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't just timing out before it gets a chance to do its work? The sockets may be limited resources causing the requests to open them to queue up.

Comment: you *do* realize that you do this all in parallel? Probably your OS cant hold up 15000 TCP connections. You probably should do it in chunks (like always only have 1000 connections open)